# Facebook Fan Page Tweak

Tags: facebook, fbml

I need to ask a question about facebook fan page. I need to create a page which user can only see if they Likes the page otherwise blury view of the page.

The thing I want is already created by some one and I don't know how to copy that.
*[url redacted -msw]*

Can you write FBML for this here?

Umair

Comment: It's just a page that makes it look like you need to "like" it for access, but you don't. As this looks like possible spam I'm taking out the link and voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly what you're trying to do, but do you already know about `<fb:visible-to-connection>`? For example:

```
<fb:visible-to-connection>
   <!-- do something -->
<fb:else>
   <!-- do something else -->
</fb:else>
</fb:visible-to-connection>
```

Comment: it looks like a condition to check whether the current user has liked the page or not. right?